# cron job wont execute the script

Tags: scripts, cron

I have the below script

```
#!/bin/sh

tail -fn1 /app/agile/agile931/agileDomain/servers/01mustgagl01.natusmed.natus.com-AgileServer/logs/agileDomain.log| \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "OutOfMemory"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
                ##--Mail the Report--
(
  echo "To: Dutta@abc.com"
  echo "From: AGILE ADMIN"
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; "
  echo "Subject: OOM Alert"
  echo
  ) | /usr/lib/sendmail -t

    fi
done
```

```
$ ./OOMERROR.sh

exit
```

It run fine when executed manually but wont run with the below cron job.

```
0 3 * * * agile /path/to/script/OOMERROR.sh
```

the syslog shows an entry and no  errors but i wont receive the email.

Comment: What is `agile` in the cron job line?

Comment: @Olathe The user name.

Comment: In which crontab file?

Comment: @A.B., assuming you're correct, I've answered how to get user `agile` to run that command via `cron`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the user who's executing the job in a `cron` job line. You can see the correct format by running `man 5 crontab` in a terminal.

Each user has their own separate crontab (`cron` job table). To edit `agile`'s crontab, open a terminal and run:

```
su agile
crontab -e
```

This will open `agile`'s crontab in a text editor. Insert the `cron` job line you have above without the username:

```
0 3 * * * /path/to/script/OOMERROR.sh
```

Now save the file and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're missing a `#` in the sha-bang.

Secondly I would recommend putting the entire path of your `agile` executable
and thirdly I would reformat the file as it seem to be a mess.

I would also suggest checking other log files as there are many different reasons why that mail wasnt sent and try adding logging support to that script if anything on it should fail.